# Run same script on under different schema - postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5

I have a script called `populate.sql` which contains create tables.

```
CREATE TABLE "EXAMPLE" (
.................
..............
);
CREATE TABLE "BlaBla" (
..........
........
);
CREATE TABLE ...
```

This script creates more than 20 tables. I want to run this `populate.sql` on top of different schemas. Let's say I want to run this script on `schema1`, `schema2` and `schema3`.

Then I can write;

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "schema1";
SET SCHEMA 'schema1';
```

on `populate.sql` and create those tables on **one** schema.

how can I create those tables on all schema within one psql command?

As far as I feel I have to do FOR LOOP on psql and create schema first and create tables on top of that scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables will get created in the currently set [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html) (if not otherwise specifically set in the create statement).

You could use a loop. In that loop you have to set the searchpath to your schema.

```
DO 
$$
  DECLARE schemaname text;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP

    schemaname := 'schema' || i::text;

    execute 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || schemaname;
    execute 'SET SCHEMA ' || schemaname;    
    execute 'SET search_path TO ' || schemaname;

    -- conent of populate.sql

  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

You cannot call external scripts inside this `do block` as mentioned by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130366/run-same-script-on-under-different-schema-postgres/40130988#comment67531980_40130988) in the comments. Therefore this answer is only relevant if you want to extend your `populate.sql` file and wrap this `do block` around it.

Comment: But you can't include a SQL script from inside a `do` block